# Error when using SfDateRangePicker Flutter

Tags: flutter

This error happens as soon as I add the import statement:
`import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/datepicker.dart';`
Remaining code is not needed to recreate this error

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/datepicker.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: SfDateRangePicker(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Error:

```
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.48/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:7596:37: Error: The argument type 'ScrollableState?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ScrollableState' because 'ScrollableState?' is nullable and 'ScrollableState' isn't.
 - 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
        scrollableState: Scrollable.of(context),
```

Comment: i am also facing the same issue , did you get any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This error is mentioned on this issue.

https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/issues/730

You should fix version of syncfusion_flutter_datepicker in pubspec.yaml

```
    Don't use version:
    syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^20.4.48

    Use like this:
    syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: "20.4.44"
```

https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/issues/730#issuecomment-1413788831

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your scaffold with MaterialApp

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: SfDateRangePicker(),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting same error with this code too. `Error: The argument type 'ScrollableState?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ScrollableState' because 'ScrollableState?' is nullable and 'ScrollableState' isn't.`